# what is the shortest path to solve a matrix with unknown elements and an eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have this matrix: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}6&-2&2\\-2&3&b\\2&b&a\end{bmatrix}$$

which has: $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-2\end{bmatrix}$$ as an eigen vector.

what is the shortest path to find **a** & **b** and all eigen values and other eigen vectors

Comment: after reading your comment I have searched and found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFDu9oVAE-g) which was very helpful to know the concept of the eigenvector. so my answer to your question is (eigenvectors are a set of vectors that will not have rotation during the linear transformation process) @Dave

Comment: There’s a bit more to it than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the fundamental definition of an eigenvector of the matrix $A$: it’s a nonzero vector $\mathbf v$ such that $A\mathbf v=\lambda\mathbf v$ for some scalar $\lambda$. Plug the given matrix and vector into this equation and you will get a system of equations for $a$, $b$ and $\lambda$.

Comment: I didn't get how did you get the last equation `(Av)×v=0`.
but is it ok to use the kernel which is `(A-λI)×v=0`
I tried it and I get that `λ=2`; `a=b=-1`

Comment: $A\mathbf v=\lambda\mathbf v$ basically says that $A\mathbf v$ is parallel to $\mathbf v$. The cross product of parallel vectors is $0$. $(A-\lambda I)\mathbf v=0$ is the same equation as $A\mathbf v=\lambda\mathbf v$, just with all of the terms moved to the left.